# Creating an array of Queue<T> in an F# class

Tags: f#

How do I create an array of `Queue<float>` and initialize it in F#?

I was trying something like this, but it is a weird C# small (besides the fact that the compiler can't resolve the overloading of the Queue constructor).

```
type MyQueues(size) = 
    let queues = Queue<float>(capacity:size) array
    do
        // Initialize queues somehow.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let queues = Array.init arraysize (fun index -> (* initialize queue here *) )
```

or

```
let queues = [| for i in 1 .. arraysize -> (* initialize queue here *) |]
```

In most cases F# compiler will infer the type of array from provided initializing function. `arraysize` here is a capacity of the array not the queue size which you would provide in initializer function.

```
let queues = Array.init arraysize (fun index -> new Queue<float>(queuecapacity) )
```